# Visual Studio - C# - multiple assemblies with same namespace conflict - alias get ignored

Tags: c#, visual-studio, alias, revit-api

I'm working on a Plugin for a software (Revit) using its API (RevitAPI.dll).

Some functions in the API have been changed in the latest version 2022 so I'm trying to implement these differences in my code.

I'm loading the 2020 API with the alias rvt20api and the 2022 as rvt22api - they have the same namespaces inside.

My problem is that in the 2022 there should be a class called *ForgeTypeId* but its giving me the CS0234 error (not found) when calling it.

I've opened the RevitAPI.dll (2022) and confirmed that the Class is indeed inside there and if i load just the 2022 API assembly then Visual Studio sees that and is happy but when I load both assemblies then the error. Seems it's almost reading the rvt20api namespace even tho I'm calling the rvt22api one.

[image]

[image]

**Short-term question :** how do I fix this ? Am i missing something (not an expert) ?

**Long-term question :** what is the most appropriate method to go with when working with multiple external api versions?
Would it be using the *Shared Project* approach ?

Comment: Could you share a bit more of the code?  Maybe a working example?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating aliases for each, like so:

```
extern alias rvt20api;
extern alias rvt22api;
using rvt20apidb = rvt20api::Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using rvt22apidb = rvt22api::Autodesk.Revit.DB;

// then within the code
var foo = rvt22apidb.forgeTypeId;
```

Docs on this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias).

Comment: tried but didnt work. that bit of code literally works the moment i unload the RevitAPI (2020). and stops when i load that back in - without changing anything in the code.

Comment: Weird.  I notice you specify the 2020 before the 2022.  Maybe try switching the order and seeing if that does anything, put the 2022 first.

Comment: ok, I'm embarassed to say that I found the solution -- the old but never too old trick of closing vs and re-open it worked..

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you had already done that.  I guess its still useful to mention it upfront anyway, just in case.  I know I've forgotten to use Occam's Razor and try that first sometimes, too.

Comment: ok, the old trick of closing and re-opening vs fixed the problem with that specific class but now there is another class giving the error (one that is present in the 20 and not in the 22 this time) -- can you confirm I'm aliasing correctly? in the properties on the right i overwrite the global to the name above and then simply add extern alias name ? is there some other things to be done? in the docs link above i've read you have to do something in the command prompt ? I'm not sure how to deal with that can someone explain it ?

Comment: @cafu23 would you happen to have detailed instruction on how to implement "extern alias" on Revit that you could share? i would like to test this method vs Shared Project or this.